# Why am I getting "Failed to request resource" when posting to a users wall on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using `artdarek/oauth-4-laravel` so the user can login via Facebook and post to their feed. I'm able to login in via Facebook using the following bit of code

```
// get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = $token->getAccessToken();

        // Send a request with it
        $user = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );
```

...
And everything works as expected. In the App I also have a share button, but when I try and share I get the following error

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuth\\Common\\Http\\Exception\\TokenResponseException","message":"Failed to request resource.","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/myApp\/vendor\/lusitanian\/oauth\/src\/OAuth\/Common\/Http\/Client\/StreamClient.php","line":68}}
```

Here is the code that I'm using for posting

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) ) {

        $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

        // $user = json_decode( $fb->request( "/me?access_token={$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']}" ), true );

        $postMessage = json_decode( $fb->request
            ( 
                'POST', 
                "/me/feed?access_token={$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']}",
                array (
                    'message' => 'This is a test message'
                )
            ), 
        true );

        return $postMessage;
    }
```

I know that the `$_SESSION[]` is set because I ran the commented out line first and it was returning what I expected. But the code for posting on the wall is giving me that error mentioned earlier.

Please help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake ... The call is supposed to be as follows

```
$postMessage = json_decode( $fb->request
            ( 

                "/me/feed?access_token={$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']}",
                'POST', 
                array (
                    'message' => 'This is a test message'
                )
            ), 
        true );
```

The route is supposed to be first and then the POST.